# Configurar un control dentro de un LinearLayout padre

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, linearlayout

Tengo un `LinearLayout` padre que contiene la propiedad;  `android:gravity="center"`
con eso todos los controles dentro de este se centraran, ahora bien necesito que algunos controles estén a la izquierda por ejemplo. ¿ Alguna idea ?

**XML**

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Iniciar Sesión"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_account_box_black_24dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_lock_black_24dp"
            android:hint="Contraseña"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Mostrar contraseña"
        android:textColor="#004D40" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:text="Recordar cuenta"
        android:textColor="#004D40" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Aceptar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="¡Recuperar contraseña!"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Como cual deseas se posicione a la izquierda?

Comment: Los checkbox pero ya lo resolví, cambiando a un relative @jorgesys

Answer (score 0):

Al componente que quieres que esté a la izquierda ponle esto:

```
android:layout_gravity="left"
```

Si esto no te funciona, pon el componente que quieres alinearlo a la izquierda dentro de un RelativeLayout que tenga match_parent en width , luego lo alineas a la izquierda del RelativeLayout :).

```
<RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Como sabras el android:layout_gravity="left" que tenga el padre, tomara todos por defecto por ende no funciona si lo usas individualmente, y la idea era no añadir otro contenedor.

Comment: entonces usa ConstraintLayout o RelativeLayout en lugar del LinearLayout :)

Comment: Si ya lo hice, no quedo de otra Jaja

Comment: jaja ok :) , está bien